# Create and save xls files in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to create an xls files using c# like this

```
protected void ExportToExcel(DataSet dset, int TableIndex, HttpResponse Respone, string Felename)
    {
        Respone.Clear();
        Respone.Charset = "";
        Respone.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Respone.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Felename + ".xls");
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();

        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = dset.Tables[TableIndex];
        gv.DataBind();
        gv.RenderControl(hw);
        Respone.Write(sw.ToString());
        Respone.End();
    }
```

It is working fine for me. But it is opening that created xls file after successfull completion. But i want to save the file in my folder without opening and asking my permision.

How can i save automatically..

Thanks in advance

Comment: This SO thread and [answer link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871115/what-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-write-into-excel-file-using-c/871142#871142) is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Change the content-type to application/x-unknown - depending on the browser this should only offer a save option as it won't recognise it as an Excel file.

Also, be aware that you are actually just saving an HTML file with an Excel extension, it isn;t a true Excel file.

Comment: oh then is there any other way to export my dataset to excel file? can you give me a sample code

Comment: You either need to use Excel interop, or buy a third party component to do this.  The HTML way will work to a certain degree.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for.NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can save to an Excel workbook from a DataTable.

See the **DataTable to Excel Workbook** C# or VB sample on the SpreadsheetGear ASP.NET Excel Reporting Sample page [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx).

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC